# Is it ever necessary for a <script> tag to go in the <head>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have read in the docs of some third party providers (e.g. adsense) that their script must go in the `<head>`.

For `async` scripts I'm fairly sure this is untrue since the async flag doesn't guarantee anything about when the script will be executed. But I'm curious about non-async scripts too. Does it makes sense to say that a script tag *must* go in the `<head>`?

(This is assuming that there isn't any code in the page that relies upon some script having loaded).

To be clear, my question isn't "is it a good idea", or "what are the performance benefits".

It's more like: "is it technically possible that a script could NOT work, because it isn't in the `<head>`?"

Thanks!

Comment: My personal rule of thumb is that if the page requires a script for anything useful to display on the page, then you may as well include it in the head. Anything that adds functionality later should go down just before the closing body tag. I'm yet to write a page where this micro-optimisation makes any real difference though...

Answer (score 2):

A `<script></script>` in the `<head>` tag will stop the DOM from parsing until the script has loaded.  Put scripts here that need to be loaded before the DOM is parsed.  Don't put any unnecessary scripts here, as it stops the DOM from parsing.  That results in a slow-to-load page.

See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/47589

Comment: It doesn't necessarily stop *parsing*, it stops *rendering* and *executing*; but it may continue parsing for other non-blocking resources.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily stop anything, the behaviour depends on whether it's `async` or `defer` or neither. @amy what would an example be of a script that needs to be loaded before the DOM is parsed? (other than scripts that are relied upon further down the page).

Comment: Any script that creates custom web components would need to load before the DOM is parsed.  Otherwise, the DOM parser won't know how to handle the custom elements.

Comment: Any script that uses `document.write` would need to be loaded before the DOM as well.  `document.write` *after* the DOM has loaded will clear the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Amy. Technically `document.write` just needs to be used before the document is _closed_. It can safely go in the HTML anywhere before the closing body tag (just not in async scripts). Interesting about web components, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) on the script tag does not place any requirements on the location of a script tag.  In fact it seems that the modern trend is now to put scripts at the very end of the body.

Comment: True, but for a reason, to not block the ui, unless you really need the script before

Answer (score 0):

A  tag can be placed anywhere in the html page, But placing in the  tag will slow down the creation of DOM elements in the browser, because browser needs to get all the script tags and move to html elements,

The best practice is to keep the script tag at the bottom of DOM elements, because the visual html elements will be loaded before the script js getting load.

It mainly depends on the functionality of the script and the business logic of the page.